# DocuSign API integration issue with RESTful Web Services : javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar

Tags: api, jersey, jwt, docusignapi, javax.ws.rs

My project is using DocuSign API to post Envelope with the **Java** client:

**docusign-esign-java-3.2.0.jar**

It works fine, but the project also needs to use jCloud with another lib dependency:

**javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar**

The server (tomcat) gets an exception when calling the JWT authent of DocuSign:

```
Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes
```

Is it possible to fix this dependency problem without exploring the DocuSign sources?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO.
depending on the dependency management program you are using , you can print a tree and then investigate if there is any conflict.
for gradle,

```java
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

for *Maven*

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Also, generally before that message you will see a Java Exception. If you add that or look at it, it may throw more light on the problem.

best wishes.

Comment: Yes thank you, we use maven and Jcloud needs a recent Jersey/RESTfull API lib.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we (DocuSign) have this issue logged as an [issue](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/issues/85) for the SDK and as DocuSign internal ticket DCM-3324.

Please ask your DocuSign representative to add your organization information to DCM-3324 to help raise the priority of the issue. Thank you.

Comment: ok thank you, I will ask my representative, I have read the tickets, we can clone the project to fix the dependency or isolate docusign in a separated container... but the SDK has to be fixed by Docusign since 1 year.